# Proving that transitive $R-$action implies $M$ is a simple module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation, modules

Here is the question I want to answer:

A module is simple if it is not the zero module and it has no proper nonzero submodule.

$(a)$ Let $M$ be an $R-$module. Show that the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $M$ is a simple $R-$module.
2. for any nonzero $x,y \in M$ there exists $r \in R$ such that $rx = y.$(i.e. the action of $R$ on $M$ is transitive)

I managed to prove $1 \implies 2.$ For $2 \implies 1,$ here is my trial (after getting some help from kind volunteers here):

Assume that $M$ is an $R-$module and assume that for any nonzero $x,y \in M$ there exists $r \in R$ such that $rx = y$ (i.e. the action of $R$ on $M$ is transitive). We want to show that $M$ is a simple $R-$module i.e. it is non-zero and it has no non-zero proper submodules.

First, $M \neq 0$ because the $R-$action on $M$ is a non-zero action. **Is this reasoning correct?**

Second, Suppose that $S \subset M$ is a non-zero submodule. We want to show that $S = M.$ If $S \neq M,$ then $\exists m \in M \setminus S$ **But then I do not know how to complete this argument, could anyone help me in completing it please?**

Comment: Hm, no the action is stil transitive on the zero module. I think $M \neq 0$ should be added as a hypothesis in $2$. Otherwise, it's vacuously true for the zero module; there are no nonzero $x,y$ to begin with.

Comment: @guidoar yeah but the action requires a nonzero $x$ as the hypothesis said. Does not that make $M$ nonzero?

Comment: The statement "for each nonzero $x,y \in M$ we have blah" is satisfied when $M = 0$. We indeed have blah for *each* nonzero $x,y$ because there are no such $x,y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** to show that $M$ is simple, you can equivalently prove that $M \neq 0$ but $M = Rx$ for all nonzero $x \in M$.

> Indeed if $M$ is simple and $x$ nonzero, then $(x)$ is a nonzero submodule, and it must coincide with $M$. Conversely, let's show that $M$ is simple. If $S$ is a nonzero submodule, it contains some nonzero $x$. But then $M = (x) \subset S \subset M$, hence $M = S$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: And the part of $M \neq 0$ how can I handle it (other than putting it as a hypothesis)?

Comment: Let me put it this way. Suppose that $M = 0$. Does it satisfy $2$? If it does not, then we should have some non zero $x$ and $y$ and $rx \neq y$ for all $r \in R$. Can you find such **nonzero** $x$ and $y$ in $M = 0$?

Comment: I am understanding that $M = 0$ satisfies 2. But I need to prove that $M$ is simple. So according to what you said there is no way of saying that $M \neq 0$ other than adding it to our hypothesis. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, $M$ can satisfy $(2)$ but fail to be simple, if $M = 0$. It's one of these 'vacuous truth' border cases. As in my comment; try to prove the opposite, that the action $M = 0$  is not transitive (we can't).

Comment: In your spoiler, in the last statement, how did you get $M = (x)$ even thought we are still proving that $M$ is simple?

Comment: Because the hypothesis is $M = (x)$ for all $x \neq 0$. My bad, my notation should have been consistent; here $(x) = Rx = \{r \cdot x : r \in R\}$.

Comment: p.s.: one still has to prove $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$, using the hint.

Comment: Is the statement of the question wrong?

Comment: Yes, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not equivalent. But $(1)$ and $(2)' :=$ "$M$ is nonzero and satisfies $(2)$" are equivalent. Your proof of $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ need not change. For the converse you can use the hint

Comment: Can you adjust your comment please?

Comment: How did you use the hypothesis in your proof?